# How did WordPress link an empty page at dashboard to an actual php file?

Tags: frontpage, template-hierarchy

### I set these 2 settings under WordPress dashboard » Reading:

- `Homepage` dropdown: set to `home` (an empty wordpress page I created in dashboard).
- `Posts page` dropdown: set to `blog` (an empty wordpress page I created in dashboard).

### Which PHP files WordPress is loading:

- Accessing `http://localhost:82` loads this php file `front-page.php`
- Accessing `http://localhost:82/blog` loads this php file `index.php`

### My question is:

In dashboard reading settings, I only chose empty pages (titled home & blog) but how on earth did WordPress `link` the empty pages to corresponding php files? Even though I didn't use `Template Name` in the php files.

Kindly note, I read the `Template Hierarchy`. But I doubt it's related to this.

Comment: It absolutely is related to the template hierarchy. It uses the template hierarchy to choose what template to use. You should review that documentation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats how wordpress template works

`front-page.php` is the very first file that wordpress check for the homepage and to be use as a template, if it doesn't exists it checks another file in specific order like `page-slug.php`,  `page-id.php`, `page.php` until it reaches index.php

the blog/posts page would first check if `home.php` exist and if not it will use `index.php`

all the url sturcture would end-up in `index.php` if their template doesn't exist.

Creating pages, posts in the back-end only interact with the database, the rendering of those content in user browser are handled by php files in a template heriarchy

Comment: here's a visual guide of wordpress template heriarchy https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I'm lost as I found nothing on the hierarchy documentation link regarding WordPress blog/posts landing page: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy So before I mark yours as answer, can you please refer me to any link which backups your saying: "the blog/posts page would first check if `home.php` exist and if not it will use `index.php`"

Comment: open that link above its a visual diagram of template heriarchy,
Its also explains here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display

Comment: Got it, but this seems against conventions, there should be another filename than home.php & index.php to use for blogs\posts page. Additionally this paragraph title `Home Page display` is a bit misleading as it covers the `posts page`.

Comment: I agree, its a bit misleading and confusing for those starting with wordpress, it should have never called  `home.php`, but rather `blog.php` or `blogs.php`

Comment: buy hey, almost everything in wordpress is against convention sooo  